# Foundation 5 topbar not working on smartphone

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, themes, zurb-foundation

I'm developing a WordPress theme powered by Foundation 5. Everything seems work well, but something is wrong when I switch to smartphone.
As you can see in the image below, when resizing the browser window on desktop, foundation topbar collapses to small screen mode. 
Unfortunately, if I access the page from my mobile browser, the the text in the topbar becomes smaller and the menu does not collapse.

here is header.php code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

        <header class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="contain-to-grid">
            <nav id="nav" role="navigation" class="top-bar" data-topbar>
                <ul class="title-area">
                    <li class="name">
                        <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                    </li>
                    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                </ul>

                <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'right', 'walker' => new Foundation_Walker()) ); ?>
                </section>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="container" class="row">
```

The image below shows what appears in my desktop browser:

[image: Resized window in forefox for mac]

---

As you can see, the menu collapse regularly.

The second image shows what happens in google chrome on android:

[image: mobile chrome]

---

Same problem on iPad: the text is small and the menu does not collapse.

Hope somebody could help me.

Here is a live example: http://htmlintro.altervista.org/wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

Solved!
I did not include the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: nice one dude. Apparently some of Foundation's examples are outdated.